# how to quieten output from spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to automate spark-submit jobs for spark on bluemix, but I'm receiving a lot of output (e.g. file upload status).  This verbose output is fine for manually running spark-submit, but it is just noise when trying to execute if from another script.

Is there a way to quieten the output from the **bluemix custom spark-submit script**?

---

**Update:**

The output I'm trying to quieten is that generated from the spark-submit script, for example:

```
Uploading ./truststore.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3103    0    99  100  3004     60   1835  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  1835
```

I am *not* trying to quieten the output from spark, so quietening `log4j` will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this what exactly you want:-

Just redirect everything to `/dev/null`

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap credentials/vcap.json --deploy-mode cluster \
    --master https://x.x.x.x:8443 --files abc.txt hellopy.py \
    file://abc.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can quiet warnings and infos this way, if you use python, but shuld be similar in other languages too:

```
def quiet_logs(sc):
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel(logger.Level.ERROR)
logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel(logger.Level.ERROR)

sc=SparkContext()
quiet_logs(sc)
```