# how to keep spark-submit from printing warnings to stdout

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

spark-submit prints some warnings to stdout. Example:

```
spark-submit --master yarn myscript.py 2>/dev/null
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead is set but does not apply in client mode.
# followed by the actual output of myscript.py
```

This makes it impossible (or at least unproportionally hard) to use the script's output in another script.

I want to remove all messages from spark-submit from stdout, and only keep the output coming directly from myscript.py

---

I am on spark 1.4.1

---

I am aware, that I could probably remove the warning by removing the problematic property, but I want to make sure stdout stays clean, even if another warning pops up.

---

this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219811/how-to-quieten-output-from-spark-submit), because I don't want to quiet myscript, but rather everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid log levels include: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE, WARN

if using SparkContext

```
my_spark_context.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

if using SparkSession

```
my_spark_session.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding yoursparkcontext.setLogLevel("ERROR") after you create your SparkContext object.